# Custom React App - Fetch API error when deploying to Heroku

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, heroku

I've built a small app in `React` (not using CRA).

I've deployed to `Heroku` and it's uploaded fine, but I'm having one issue in which a static `JSON` file I created myself isn't fetching (Works fine locally).

I'm getting the below error:

[image]

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

I've tried creating a `public` folder outside of `src` but that didn't help either.

I have a basic Express setup:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: That usually denotes that HTML is being rendered and isn't json. console.log what it is and I'm assuming it's HTML with an error message.

Comment: You can use dev tools to see what the response is that you're getting. If you right-click your browser, click inspect, click network, click Fetch/XHR, and then trigger whatever causes `getPlayers` to execute (eg: refresh your page), you should be able to see your request and the response that you're getting back.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JSON files are accessible. it sounds like you are trying to fetch a file and returning an HTML/XML response. it usually happens when your file has some error.